# css jquery hide one div, show another

Tags: jquery, css, hide, show

I am having a challenge.
I have 2 `divs`, one set to `display:none;` in the css when the page loads
I have two corresponding links. When the user clicks on `link1` I would like to show `div1` and hide `div2`. And when the user clicks on `link2` I would like to show `div2` and hide `div1`.

I have not been able to get this to work! Any help much appreciated.
S

Comment: You will need to use javascript code to achieve that and change the div class based on what button was clicked

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here an example:

```
$(function () {
  $(".div1, .div2").hide();

  $(".link1, .link2").bind("click", function () {
    $(".div1, .div2").hide();        

    if ($(this).attr("class") == "link1")
    {
      $(".div1").show();
    }
    else
    {
      $(".div2").show();
    }
  });

});
```

And here is the [**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/cEJtA/)

Answer (score 4):

Firstly,please provide the HTML for your question, whenever you ask one here.

Secondly, you could do something like..

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#div1").hide();
    $("#link1").on("click",function(){
        $("#div1").show();
        $("#div2").hide();
    });
    $("#link2").on("click",function(){
        $("#div2").show();
        $("#div1").hide();
    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Depending on your HTML structure

if something like this

```
​<a href='#'>link1</a>
<a href='#'>link2</a>
<div> div for link 1</div>
<div> div for link 2</div>
```

then jQuery code would look like this

```
$('a').click(function(e){
    $('div').eq($(this).index()).show();
    $('div').not($('div').eq($(this).index()).hide();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/NXdyb/

Answer (score 1):

Are you deadset on jquery? This can be done simply with normal old JavsScript.

```
function switchVisible() {

if (document.getElementById['div1'].style.visibility == 'visible') {
    document.getElementById['div1'].style.visibility = 'hidden';
    document.getElementById['div2'].style.visibility = 'visible';
}
else {
    document.getElementById['div1'].style.visibility = 'visible';
    document.getElementById['div2'].style.visibility = 'hidden';
}

}
```

Then have in your link1:

```
<a href="/blah" onclick="javascript:switchVisible();">
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a very simple principle...you can achieve it many ways, this is just one example.

[Ignore the selectors, I'm lazy.](http://jsfiddle.net/jcCRj/)

The HTML ->

```
<a href="#"> Show Div 1 </a> | <a href="#"> Show Div 2 </a>
<br/><br/>
<div id="div1"> Div 1 </div>
<div id="div2"> Div 2 </div>
```

The CSS ->

```
#div1{
  display:none;   
}
```

The jQuery ->

```
$('a:eq(0)').click(function(){
  $('#div1').toggle();
  $('#div2').toggle();    
});
$('a:eq(1)').click(function(){
  $('#div2').toggle();
  $('#div1').toggle();   
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this example it might help you out: http://jsfiddle.net/MUtPy/2/  ^^  There are many ways to do this in Jquery but this example should certainly get u started =)

Answer (score 0):

That fiddle helped me, it is really understandable : http://jsfiddle.net/bipen/zBdFQ/1/

```
$("#link1").click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $("#div1").slideDown(slow);
  $("#div2").slideUp(slow);
});

$("#link2").click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $("#div1").slideUp(slow);
  $("#div2").slideDown(slow);
});
```