# I need a switchable button, and I'm rusty

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, button, switch-statement

I need a switchable button. Basically I need it to switch between design A with link A, to design B with link B, and back to design A with link A, when clicked again.
I have been failing miserably with CSS and JavaScript, simply because I havent been coding for 7+ years. Its back to noob Q's.

My thoughts are that I want a .gif file with a link, to change into another .gif file with another link, when clicked, the last one changing back to the first one when clicked.
Another also very fine solution would be highlighting a piece of text (i.e. with CSS) and then changing the link with the highlight, and then removing the highlight reverting to the first link again. I'm open to solution.

I hope i make sense and I hope someone can help.

Comment: A simple solution would be to have both buttons on the page and use the onClick function combined with the add/remove class, to switch between CSS display none/block. I found also this that could help: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11761049/css-jquery-hide-one-div-show-another](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11761049/css-jquery-hide-one-div-show-another)

Comment: What i got from your question is that you have two different stylings (css), when you click on first link, first one applies and when you click on second, the second one applies. One easy way to do it through CSS/JS is by switching classes.. You know element classes. for example: <div class = "class1"></<div>, in your css, .class1{/*The styling you want to apply for first link*/} then when user clicks on second link, you change the class to 'class2', in your css, inside .class2{} define the styling you want for link two.. i hope you got the rough idea

Answer (score 1):

The best way to solve this is to wrap both designs under one parent div which will be in charge of the state. This way you only have to toggle a CSS class in one place to manage which one is visible. Here is an example with jQuery.

**HTML**

```
<div class="controls">
  <a class="control active js-show-design1" href="#">Link 1</a>
  <a class="control js-show-design2" href="#">Link 2</a>
</div>

<div class="state-container">

  <div class="design1"> Some content </div>
  <div class="design2"> Some other content </div>

</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.control.active {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
}

.state-container .design2{
  display: none;
}

.state-container.show-design2 .design2{
  display: block;
}
.state-container.show-design2 .design1{
  display: none;
}
```

**JQUERY**

```
controls = $('.control');
ctr = $('.state-container');

$('.js-show-design2').click(function(){
  controls.removeClass('active');
  this.addClass('active');

  ctr.addClass('show-design2');
});

$('.js-show-design1').click(function(){
  controls.removeClass('active');
  this.addClass('active');

  ctr.removeClass('show-design2');
});
```

Note that this solution is meant for a toggle between only two views. You would need some adjustments to extend it to support 3 or more.