# Hide clicked element and show the element right after it using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I want to put questions in some HTML text, with answers that are hidden until the user clicks on the button/link/etc, which then disappears, and now showing the answer. The answer replaces the space used by the disappearing button/link.  I would like to have questions like this go down the page in the article, not just one.

So for example, where "[my thoughts]" is a button or link:

```
text text text
Does ABC need anything?
   [my thoughts]

text text text, text, text.
```

clicking on [my thoughts] then becomes:

```
text text text
Does ABC need anything?
   ABC needs a a lot of DEF, and it will help ABC too if things are taken
   slowly.  Additionally, ABC needs a lot of sleep.
text text text, text, text.
```

Per comment: This is the [closest thing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11761049/css-jquery-hide-one-div-show-another) I found, but isn't exactly right, as I want it to keep using it going down the page:

Thanks per Gothdo, I'm working with:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Test3</title>
    <script>
      $("button").click(function()
      {
        $(this).hide();
        $(this).next().css("visibility", "visible");
      });
    </script>
    <style type="text/css" >
        div {
           visibility: hidden;
        }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <button>test</button><div>test test test</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please show your attempts; not many are willing to code a solution for you from scratch when you haven't tried anything yourself(that we're aware of).

Comment: you can absolute position [my thoughts] relative to the question with css.

Comment: @Daedalus, I added the best example I found, in the question.

Comment: @Ray Please include your implementation, and describe why it doesn't work for you.

Comment: @Felipe, can I just shrink the space taken by "[my thoughts]", not just hide it?

Comment: When you are asking question related to HTML and Javascript, You need to show your attempts. Understand you are defining a use case and I totally agree with @Daedalus

Comment: @Daedalus.  Working on it.  I have a hope that something like this type of need is fairly common and someone knows how to do it.

Comment: @Ray I guess you don't want your layout to move every time a question is clicked, if that is the case create an empty box with it's own widht and height to contain the answer

Comment: @Ray it sounds simple yet if it's not close to what you wanted, then we'll be going back and forth trying to read your mind.

Comment: @Ray see my answer, I'm not sute if that's what you really want so let me know what can be improved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code:

```
$element.click(function() {
  $(this).hide();
  $(this).next().css("visibility", "visible");
});
```

Code snippet:

```js
$("button").click(function() {
  $(this).hide();
  $(this).next().css("visibility", "visible");
});
```

```css
div {
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>test</button>
<div>test test test</div>
```

Comment: The hide is right, messing with that, but didn't get the .next().show() to pick up the next element, which has it's visibility set as hidden.  But what you are listing is exactly what I want to do, if I can get it tor work.

Comment: where is the "next" now though?

Comment: @Ray I accidentally removed it; see now. I also added a code snippet.

Comment: This looks good, just giving other answers their respect, thanks Gothdo

Comment: I have no idea why I can't get this to run as a page.  Can you please assist, look at my copy of it in the question, not sure where to put it otherwise.

Comment: @Ray You have to either put your script at the end of document, or wrap it with `$(function(){ /* the code */ });`.

Comment: Thanks, I see.  I looked up the jquery next documentation, https://api.jquery.com/next/, and am not clear why I can't do another method on the selected element, like fadeIn(1000), which would look better than just using the setting the css visibility.  Do you know if this is somehow limited using next()?

Comment: @Ray Using `.next()` returns the same object as if you select it using normal selector. It shouldn't cause any problems.

Comment: @Ray Try something like this: `$(this).next().hide().css("visibility", "visible").fadeIn();` (see [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ks4r8o9z/)).

Answer (score 1):

Something like that? The text appears and the button disappears

```js
$(function(){
  var answer = $(".answer");
  var clickable = $(".clickable");
  answer.hide()
  $(".button").on("click", function(){
    $(this).hide()
    if(!answer.is(":visible")){
      answer.show().addClass("clickable")
    }else{
      answer.hide();
    }
  })
  //EXTRA:: makes the button and answer toggle on click
  $("body").on("click", ".clickable", function(){
    $(this).hide();
    if(!answer.is(":visible")){
      $(".button").show();
    }
  })
})
```

```css
.button{
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px;
  background: powderblue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="text">text Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolorem, asperiores. </div>
 <div class= "question">Does ABC need anything?</div>
 <div class="button"> [my thoughts]</div>
 <div class="answer"> ABC needs a a lot of DEF, and it will help ABC too if things are taken
   slowly.  Additionally, ABC needs a lot of sleep.</div>
 <div class="text">text Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolorem, asperiores.</div>
```

Away to do it with multiple questions.

```js
$(function(){

  $(".answer").hide()
  $(".button").on("click", function(){
    $(this).hide()
    // go to the parent of the button that was  and find the child `answer`
    if(!$(this).parent(".parent").find(".answer").is(":visible")){
      $(this).parent(".parent").find(".answer").show().addClass("clickable")
    }else{
      $(this).parent(".parent").find(".answer").hide();
    }
  })
  $("body").on("click", ".clickable", function(){
    $(this).hide();
    if(!$(this).parent(".parent").find(".answer").is(":visible")){
      // $(".button").show();
      $(this).parent(".parent").find(".button").show()
    }
  })


})
```

```css
.button{
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px;
  background: powderblue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="parent">
  <div class="text">text Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolorem, asperiores. </div>
  <div class= "question">Does ABC need anything?</div>
  <div class="button"> [my thoughts]</div>
  <div class="answer"> ABC needs a a lot of DEF, and it will help ABC too if things are taken
    slowly.  Additionally, ABC needs a lot of sleep.</div>
  <div class="text">text Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolorem, asperiores.</div>
 </div>

 <!-- Other Question -->
 <hr>
 <div class="parent">
  <div class="text"> second text text Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolorem, asperiores. </div>
  <div class= "question">Does ABC need anything?</div>
  <div class="button"> [my thoughts 2ND]</div>
  <div class="answer"> 2ND ANSWER ABC needs a a lot of DEF, and it will help ABC too if things are taken
    slowly.  Additionally, ABC needs a lot of sleep.</div>
  <div class="text">text Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolorem, asperiores.</div>
 </div>
```

Comment: Am trying for multiple ones going down the page.  Don't you need something special to get the answer right next to the button/link being clicked?

Comment: You could add the class name to the element that you want to have the effect to. I hope that is helpful. add the class button to the button div [my thoughts] etc.

Comment: Do you like the next() better, per @Gothdo answer?

Comment: if you want to add element to the section you might add siblings or HTML elements  and  `next() ` gets the sibling and not a specific element. if you target the class you get get the specific element your targeting like button. if you add element next to button `next()` might  not be your target element. Using next is good if you know how the DOM looks and you know it is going to stay that way. It has other benefits too. basically when you use classes you target the element and your not traversing through the DOM .something like that

Comment: @Ray  Added A little extra to show how to toggle the answer In case you wanted to know how to do that. click the button and the answer and they appear and disappear

Comment: Too cool, thanks Jack, for showing the toggle, I was wondering how to do that.  I'm still a little unclear about how to do two (or more) down the page with you way ... so as not to have to code a different function for each one.

Comment: I edited the answer to show another snippet. It should show it working on other areas down the page. I find the parent and then get the element (children)that are associated with that parent to do the operation. so the classes in different questions don't interfere with eac h other. I hope it works. any problems let me know

Answer (score 1):

hope this will help to you....
I have added html, css and js together. if you want you can use external css and js.I think this is what you expect.This will very easy, if you try to use bootstrap.

```
    <html>
<head>
<title></title>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<style type="text/css">
body{
  font-family: monospace;;
}

 .answer{
   display: none;

 }

</style>
<body>
<h4>text text text</h4>
<h4>Does ABC need anything</h4>
<button class="clickme">my thoughts</button>

<div>
  <span class="answer">ABC needs a a lot of DEF, and it will help ABC too if things are taken
   slowly.  Additionally, ABC needs a lot of sleep.</span>
   <span><h4>text text text text</h4></span>
<div>


<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function(){
    $(".clickme").click(function(){
      $(".answer").fadeIn(1000);
      $(".clickme").hide();
    });
 });
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I can't figure out why the last "text text text" doesn't display initially, and button is clicked, can you?

Comment: I like your fade, very nice.   Please note I need a bunch of these going down the page, and am looking at how to fade now with using the .next() as @Gothdo shows.

Answer (score 0):

```js
(function($){
  
  $hint = $('#hint');
  $question = $('.question');
  $answer = $('.answer');
  
  $hint.click(function(){
    
    $answer.html("Yes!");
  
  });
  
})(jQuery);
```

```css
.question{
  width: 200px;
  height: 50px;
  background: lightblue;
}
.answer{
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>

  <p class="question">Is my script sexy?
  <span class="answer"></span></p>
  <button id="hint">Hint</button>

</body>
</html>
```

assuming you want your question and answer to be self contained inside a box, this is the best solution to achieve that in the cleanest way possible.

Comment: Thanks Felipe, this isn't what I was looking for.  I think @Gothdo has got it.